# ampl display variable depending on a condition

Tags: ampl

suppose we have the following ampl model:

```
set objects;
set sacks;
...
var Take{objects, sacks} binary;
...
display Take;
```

after solving the optimization problem I want to display only the lines of Take that equal 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
for{o in objects, s in sacks: Take[o,s] = 1} {
    printf "\n %s %s", o,s; 
}
```