# How to display only the binary variables that are equal to 1 in console of AMPL

Tags: optimization, ampl

I'm creating an optimization model for a container terminal, where I need to allocate discharging containers into different positions in the yard, where a position is represented by sector, bay, row, tier (s,b,r,t). In AMPL, I have created a set of positions which involves (s,b,r,t) so that represents an specific container.

What I want to do, is that in the results, in the console, I want my binary variable X[i,p,s,b,r,t] to show only the values equal to 1, so if I have a lot of data, I won't see a lot of ceros on it. The variable representes if the container i, taken by the crane p, is allocated to position (s,b,r,t).

I have already tried the command displayed in this thread: [ampl display variable depending on a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49281515/ampl-display-variable-depending-on-a-condition)

Which is:

```
for{o in objects, s in sacks: Take[o,s] = 1} {
    printf "\n %s %s", o,s; 
}
```

But I don't get the part where it says: "printf "\n %s %s", o,s;". What is "\n %s %s"?

I expect to see only values equal to 1 in my console, so I can easily read which positions will be used by containers.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

> But I don't get the part where it says: "printf "\n %s %s", o,s;".
>   What is "\n %s %s"?

\n is a line break.

When you have %s within the quote marks, these are replaced by the arguments that come after the quoted text, in the order that those arguments are given.

So here, this means:

- start a new line
- print a space
- print the first argument that appears after the quoted text (i.e. the value of o)
- print another space
- print the second argument after the quoted text (i.e. the value of s)

In your case, you will want something like:

```
printf "\n %s %s %s %s %s %s", i,p,s,b,r,t;
```

with one %s for each of the six indices that you need to output.

You can tinker with this format, e.g.:

```
printf "\n%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s", i,p,s,b,r,t;
```

would print it without a leading space, and with commas instead of spaces between the indices.